# MySQL calculate ON-OFF time from datetime

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple schema

```
CREATE TABLE Stack (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `datetime` DATETIME,
  `status` VARCHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO Stack
  (`id`, `datetime`, `status`)
VALUES
  ('1', '2020-01-01 10:00:00', 'ON'),
  ('2', '2020-01-01 11:00:00', 'ON'),
  ('3', '2020-01-01 12:00:00', 'OFF'),
  ('4', '2020-01-01 12:30:00', 'OFF'),
  ('5', '2020-01-01 15:00:00', 'ON'),
  ('6', '2020-01-01 16:00:00', 'ON'),
  ('7', '2020-01-01 17:30:00', 'OFF'),
  ('8', '2020-01-01 18:00:00', 'ON');
```

Pratically is a device. This device send me datetime and the status of a machine. I need to get/calculate the ON-OFF time of the machine in format like 00:00:00, checking every line of the DB.

I have made a DB Fiddle for simplify:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dpypuY7qc8apmJfC3qrovf/2

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the interval between ON and OFF, or the total time the device is ON?

Comment: The total time the device is ON. I think i need to check every ON line and make a sort of interpolation between the first line and the second one, the second and the third and so on...

Comment: OK, but what to do with the last ON?

Comment: Since it is in realtime, the device was started at 18:00:00 and still active to NOW(). If is OFF, well is OFF

Comment: Ah, that's a real complication then.

Comment: Unfortunaly, i'm not so good with MySQL so i don't know how hard it can be

Comment: Please provide the corresponding result set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a basic one for the duration except for the last bit from 'ON' to 'NOW()'. It looks like this:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, S1.datetime, S2.datetime))) AS duration
FROM Stack AS S1,
     Stack AS S2
WHERE S1.id + 1 = S2.id AND
      S1.status = 'ON'
```

This can probably be written as a JOIN as well, most people prefer that, but that's equivalent to this. There's a bit of juggling with the times, as you can see. The result is:

```
06:30:00
```

I spotted an error in your database, there are two id's with the value 7. I changed the second one to 8 and now the result is:

```
04:30:00
```

That cannot be right. Haha... sorry, let me think. OK, checked it, and it is correct. The 06:30:00 was caused by the error in the database.

The next query will compute the remaining time at the end of the database table:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `datetime`, NOW())) AS `duration`
FROM `Stack` 
WHERE `id` = (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `Stack`) AND
      `status` = 'ON'
```

It now return the ridiculous:

```
838:59:59
```

This is not the right result, so ignore it. The date is simply too far back in the past for this query to work. To get a reasonable result from the database I changed all the dates from `2020-01-01` to `2021-01-22`.

Finally we need to combine these two. And that's relatively simple:

```
SELECT
  SEC_TO_TIME(
    (SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, S1.datetime, S2.datetime)) AS duration
     FROM Stack AS S1,
          Stack AS S2
     WHERE S1.id + 1 = S2.id AND
           S1.status = 'ON')
     +
     (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `datetime`, NOW()) AS `duration`
      FROM `Stack` 
      WHERE `id` = (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `Stack`) AND
            `status` = 'ON')
   );
```

And that should do it. Now I am sure there must be a better way to do this, but hey, it works!

Oh, if the last status is 'OFF' it results NULL. Let me work on that. This should do something:

```
SELECT
  SEC_TO_TIME(CAST(
    (SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `S1`.`datetime`, `S2`.`datetime`)) AS duration
     FROM Stack AS `S1`,
          Stack AS `S2`
     WHERE `S1`.`id` + 1 = `S2`.`id` AND
           `S1`.`status` LIKE 'ON')
     +
     IFNULL((SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `datetime`, NOW()) AS `duration`
             FROM `Stack` 
             WHERE `id` = (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `Stack`) AND
                   `status` LIKE 'ON'), 0)
   AS UNSIGNED));
```

I added the `CAST(.... AS UNSIGNED)` to remove the anything after the second.

Comment: I'll check with the original DB and let you know. I'll update the first post with the correct DB Fiddle. I'll wait for the last NOW() thank you!

Comment: If the status if OFF of the last value i get NULL with the combined query

Comment: Yes, I just saw that, I will do something about that.

Comment: Haha, really? Didn't check that, it should work... let me check.

Comment: Yeah, I had left `SEC_TO_TIME()` in the second sub-query, sloppy!

Comment: Anyway, as you see, adding the last bit upto `NOW()` complicates this query no end.

Comment: Thaks man! I'll let you know if is all ok! Thanks again

Comment: Well, isn't ok... Is my fault. We can't consider the ID since some row isn't consecutive (I didn't notice before, is a very big db) so we need to consider just the column of datetime and status. Can you help me? Don't delete previus and precious example, can be useful ;)

Comment: @g-pane You can emulate a sequential and unique row id using session variables. See: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number Note that you can only execute one query at a time, this needs two, so use the same connection to do that.

Comment: @g-pane An alternative would be to make your current id sequential and unique, usually by declaring it an auto-increment field. This might not always be possible, for instance when other tables use it as a foreign key or when rows can be deleted by design.

Answer (score 1):

You say this is about one device. This is the table you have:

```
+----+---------------------+--------+
| ID |  DATETIME           | STATUS |
+----+---------------------+--------+
|  1 | 2020-01-01 10:00:00 | ON     |
|  2 | 2020-01-01 11:00:00 | ON     |
|  3 | 2020-01-01 12:00:00 | OFF    |
|  4 | 2020-01-01 12:30:00 | OFF    |
|  5 | 2020-01-01 15:00:00 | ON     |
|  6 | 2020-01-01 16:00:00 | ON     |
|  7 | 2020-01-01 17:30:00 | OFF    |
|  8 | 2020-01-01 18:00:00 | ON     |
+----+---------------------+--------+
```

These are my conclusions:

1. We see the device is on at 10:00. Was it on before? We don't know. Hence we consider this the first switch-on time.
2. Why are we getting this? Has the device failed to send an OFF in between? Well, let's consider this "still on".
3. Switched off.
4. Why are we getting this? Has the device failed to send an ON in between? Well, let's consider this "still off".
5. Switched on.
6. Why are we getting this? Has the device failed to send an OFF in between? Well, let's consider this "still on".
7. Switched off.
8. Switched on.

This means we must always find the next status change. ON directly after ON gets ignored. Same for OFF after OFF.

Steps:

1. Add a row with the current time and OFF for easier calculation later.
2. Look into the previous row. Only keep rows that have a different status from the previous row.
3. For easier calculation, I convert the timestamps to seconds since a fixed date in the part.
4. Now it's mere aggregation and getting back from seconds only to hours, minutes, and seconds.

The query:

```
select
  sec_to_time(sum(case when 'OFF' then secs else -secs end))
from
(
  select
    timestampdiff(second, date '1990-01-01', datetime) as secs,
    status, 
    lag(status) over (order by datetime) as prev_status
  from 
  (
    select datetime, status from Sack
    union all
    select now(), 'OFF'
  ) end_row_added
) with_previous_status
where status <> prev_status or prev_status is null;
```

You need MySQL 8 for this. Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9a3e500bafb09a9b3b5295ac715b6236

Comment: Unfortunaly, my MySQL is 5.7. I can't update actually. Thanks. The table was just an example, but the structure is the same of the real. We have multiple ON for a specific reason (I have to ask why)

Comment: This can become complicated without `LAG`. In your sample data you can easily find the previous row by subtracting 1 from the ID to get the previous ID. In real world, however, it is usually not guaranteed to have consecutive IDs. A mere failure to write a row and the resulting rollback would already lead to a gap in the IDs. My first step hence would be to number all rows. In MySQL 5.7 this is done with variables somehow.

Comment: As to multiple ON: Yes, it's better to ask. If it turns out this is because of unsent OFF, then you may want to fake these by inserting OFF rows with a timestamp right in the middle of the two ONs for a reasonable estimate.

Comment: I have asked it. We need to calculate between all the ON row without interpolation. Is a requirement. And you was right, the ID aren't consecutive (didn't notice before) and I'm forced to use MySQL 5.7 so i can't use your query actually...

Comment: Look up how to number rows in MySQL in older versions. It's done with variables. You'll find examples on SO and with Google. Thus you get numbers without gaps, which helps to find the next or previous row. Or you decide not to do this in SQL altogether, but in your app with a programming language and a loop, which might be the easiest approach.

Comment: I need in MySQL since this db/view is read directly "outside", i can't use any programming language. I have search before open the thread (also about variable with @ and : ) but my actual knowledge is limited for this task.